# select random tuples but prefer old dates

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

With this table:

```
CREATE TABLE T_TEST (
id int identity,
somevalue varchar(256),
lastupdate smalldatetime
);
```

i want to select `n` random tuples which age is older than `x` days but prefer old tuples (where the lastupdate column is smallest)

my current query, `x=30, n=1000`:

```
select top 1000 * from T_TEST where lastupdate < dateadd(day, -30, getdate()) order by newid()
```

It should not work like this:

```
select * from (select top 1000 * from T_TEST where lastupdate < dateadd(day, -30, getdate()) order by lastupdate desc) t order by newid()
```

Comment: What does "it should not work like this" mean? You don't want that specific query? Why? Please explain.

Comment: Are you wanting to: (1) Choose low order dates and use newid() to order 'n' low order dates randomly? or (2) Choose newid() to 'randomize' all dates and then select the 'n' low order dates from that set? or (3) something else altogether?